# Creating a parentlist with recursive function error

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to make a parent list of my pids for each fid.

Example:

```
fid     pid
-----------
 1      0
 34     1
 35     34
 36     35
```

I tried to make a **recursive function** but I get error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 200704 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\application\modules\admin\controllers\forums\Forum_management.php on line 91
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 1

What I am trying to achive is

**If need to get parentlist for fid = 36 then should be able to echo 35, 34, 1**

> **Question:** How can I use a **recursive function** so can get pid list for example fid = 36 then should be able to echo 35, 34, 1

```
public function index() {
    $results = $this->make_parent_list('36');

    echo implode(',', $results);
}


public function make_parent_list($fid, $parents = array())
{
    $this->db->where('fid', $fid);
    $this->db->where('pid >', '0');
    $query = $this->db->get('forum');
   
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        
        foreach($query->result() as $row) {
            
            $parents[] = $row->pid;

            $this->make_parent_list($row->fid, $parents);

        }
    }   

   return $parents; 
}
```

[image]

## Update

I have now tried it this way below but when I echo it in my index `Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

```
public function make_parent_list($fid)
{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM forum WHERE fid  = '" . $fid . "'"; 
    
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    $arr = array();
    
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

        if ($row->pid) {

            $arr[] = $row->pid;

            $arr[] = $this->make_parent_list($row->pid);

        }
        
    }

    return $arr;

}

public function index() {
    $results = $this->make_parent_list('36');

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo implode(',', $result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

I have now solved it after but of googling and reading

Solution was found here [How to get all the child and grandchild categories of a parent category in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780349/how-to-get-all-the-child-and-grandchild-categories-of-a-parent-category-in-codei)

```
public functio index() {

    $all_categories = $this->make_parent_list(36);

    $arr = array();

    foreach ($all_categories as $category) {
        $arr[] = $category['pid'];
    }

    echo implode(',', $arr);
}

function make_parent_list($fid) {
    $forum_data = array();

    $forum_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM forum WHERE fid = '" . (int)$fid . "'");

    foreach ($forum_query->result() as $forum) {

        if ($forum->pid > 0) {

            $forum_data[] = array(
                'pid' => $forum->pid,
            );

            $forum_children = $this->make_parent_list($forum->pid);

            if ($forum_children) {
                $forum_data = array_merge($forum_children, $forum_data);
            }           

        }
    }

    return $forum_data;
}
```